# rosrun via ssh doesnt start a node properly

Tags: c++, linux, shell, ssh, ros

We are working with ros and try to run a node via SSH in a shell script.
We have an controlling (master) computer on which we execute the script with the following line:

```
ssh user@xxx.xxx.x.x -x "/bin/bash -c 'source /etc/profile; rosrun stargazer_alter stargazer_node'"
```

The node is getting started (it occurs in "rosnode list" and the node is also listed as a publisher in "rostopic info") but the main method seems not to be executed (neither any print lines show up nor any messages were published).

```
#include "Stargazer_listener.h"

enum STATES {config, readData};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   ROS_INFO("Test!!!! Stargazer starts!");
   ros::init(argc, argv, "stargazer_node");
   Stargazer_listener starG;
   int iFd = 0;
   char *rec_msg = (char*)malloc(BUFFSIZE * sizeof(char));
   iFd = starG.portSetup();
   STATES STATE = config;
   while(ros::ok()) {
     switch(STATE) {
       case config:
         starG.cmd(iFd, rec_msg, "~#CalcStop`");
         printf("CalcStop\n");
         starG.cmd(iFd, rec_msg, "~#CalcStart`");
         printf("CalcStart\n");
         STATE = readData;
         break;
       case readData:
         starG.publish_data(iFd, rec_msg);
         break;
     }
   }
   free(rec_msg);
   return 0;
}
```

The line "starG.portSetup()" opens the ttyUSB0 port which is not used by other processes.

The stargazer_node is getting compiled via catkin_make. According to the code, the first thing to happen should be the following print line: "ROS_INFO("Test!!!! Stargazer starts!");".
Which doesnt happen!

The same shell script command did work fine with other nodes. If we add the node to a ros ".launch" file, the same thing happens.

If I connect via ssh in a terminal (ssh user@xxx.xxx.x.x) and then run the same line (rosrun stargazer_alter stargazer_node) everything works fine!

Comment: Only a comment because it is probably not related to the question: I noticed, that your while loop is missing a `ros::spinOnce()`. It may not be necessary here as long as your are not subscribing for anything, but if you are subscribing for something in `Stargazer_listener` (the name suggests that you indeed are), it won't work without spinning (spin calls the subscriber callbacks).

Comment: The Stargazer_listener is not subscribing any topic. It is actually listening to an USB port and publishes the received messages. But thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: Okay, then it's probably fine without spinning (maybe add it nonetheless to be on the save side and avoid unforeseen bugs).

Comment: Have you solve it? I meet the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately not. As far as I can remember we had to implement it completly different. Sorry!